# Group Directory permission

Tags: files, permissions, group

you have been asked by couple of programmers to make ProjectA a group directory on a UNIX server which allows them to create files under that directory to facilitate collaborative work, but only the owner of a file or the root is permitted to rename or delete the file stored under this directory . IS that the right command (chmod g+t ProjectA) to make this happen? If not what would be the right ans? (the original permissions of ProjectA are 766), assuming that these programmers are all in the same UNIX group?

Answer (score 2):

Permissions should be `g=rwxt`. Everyone in the group needs to be able to read and write the directory. The sticky bit then says that files can only be deleted/renamed by users that have write permission to the file.